# Locating web element with Ref attribute in selenium

Tags: html, selenium, automated-tests, robotframework

I have the following element that I wish to locate using Robot Framework/Selenium Web Driver:

```
<div ref="component" class="formio-component formio-component-form  formio-component-label-hidden" id="e2cdar9">
```

If I try using the xpath in chrome's console, it detects it correctly; however, I have found no way of locating it using Robot (Xpath, full xpath, class, I can't use ID since it is randomly generated).

I think it may have something to do with the Ref attribute, since this happens on this element and all elements nested inside (Even elements with simple Name attributes won't be detected by my code), and all of these have that attribute.

Anyone knows what may be happening?
Thanks,
Andres

Comment: Are you getting any errors? like element is not found or no such element, etc ?

Comment: Yes, I'm getting the "Element With Locator ... not found".

Comment: Did you check for iframes? If there is no iframes, then you should try with dynamic wait until the page loads and displays the element.

Comment: Please show what you have tried and what errors you got for them.